# Copy IP Address reservation without replacing

Tags: powershell, replace, ip, windows-server-2012, dhcp

I am saving the DHCP reservation to CSV files using the following command:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 10.2.0.0 |Export-Csv .\scope_10_2_0_0.csv
```

I convert IP and scope addresses using the following commands:

```
$a=Import-Csv .\scope_10_2_0_0.csv
$a|foreach {$_.IPAddress=$_.IPaddress -replace "10.2.200.", "192.168.200." }
$a|foreach {$_.ScopeID=$_.ScopeID -replace "10.2.0.", "192.168.0."}
```

I want to add those DHCP reservations form $a to a 192.168.0.0 scope

```
$a | Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation
```

But I can expect that some of the IP address reservations already exists in the destination scope with the same IP but different MAC address.

What loop should I use to check it out and add the DHCP reservation which has been found a duplicate IP to the nearest possible IP available. We need to remember that when increasing the IP we are limited with the broadcast address which cannot be used and if we decrease the IP address we should not use network IP.

Fon converting IP from the dot formatted to binary the [IPv4 subnet maths with PowerShell](http://www.indented.co.uk/2010/01/23/powershell-subnet-math/) article can be useful.